why ip rule added with priority 0
I'm having strange behaviour on ubuntu server where any new 'ip rule' added is added with priority zero.
I add the rules with no priority and it used to be added to available priority.
Expected duplicate rule or filled (it is not) but did some cleanup for old rules to free it up but never used the new available priorities.
Server >> VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
Kernel >> 4.15.0-172-generic

Example
0:  from all lookup local
0:  from all iif bb2671448 lookup 7173
0:  from all oif bb2671448 lookup 7173
0:  from all iif ebb90d64d lookup 7415
0:  from all oif ebb90d64d lookup 7415
1000:   from all lookup [l3mdev-table]
32765:  from all fwmark 0x4d2 lookup 123
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

Thanks

This can be reproduced by first adding any rule with preference 0 so there are at least two present: the original 0:   from all lookup local and the new one.
Just remove all rules at preference 0 until there's only one left. It should better be the original 0: from all lookup local (or expect connectivity issues), but that's not even mandatory.
It's not even pref 0 that is special (even if that's the intention for the default setup), it's the fact that next lowest preference value is also 0, and that nothing can be created with yet-a-lower value when this value is already 0 (see last comment). Normally the value is chosen as the next lowest minus 1 (from default setup that would be 32766 (which is next after 0) -1 = 32765).

Reproducer in an user+network namespace:
$ unshare -Urnm
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
# ip rule add pref 0 from 192.0.2.2 lookup main
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
0:  from 192.0.2.2 lookup default
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
# ip rule add from 192.0.2.0/24 lookup default # affected
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
0:  from 192.0.2.2 lookup main
0:  from 192.0.2.0/24 lookup default
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
# 

Leave only one at pref 0 (even the "wrong" one as done in this demonstration):
# ip rule del lookup local # usually a bad idea
# ip rule del from 192.0.2.2 lookup main
# ip rule
0:  from 192.0.2.0/24 lookup default
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip rule add lookup local
# ip rule
0:  from 192.0.2.0/24 lookup default
32765:  from all lookup local # used next available slot
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

So: don't add a rule at priority 0 to avoid this problem.

If the intent is to have some rules happen before lookup local for special policy routing purposes, then move this one higher and insert others before. After this all new rules should be added with an explicit preference or sooner or later unwanted ordering will happen (see example below).
$ unshare -Urnm
# ip rule add pref 500 lookup local
# ip rule del pref 0
# ip rule add pref 32000 from 192.0.2.2 lookup 5000
# ip rule add from 198.51.100.3 lookup 6000
# ip rule add pref 400 from 203.0.113.4 lookup 7000
# ip rule add from 203.0.113.5 lookup 8000 
# ip rule
400:    from 203.0.113.4 lookup 7000
499:    from 203.0.113.5 lookup 8000
500:    from all lookup local
31999:  from 198.51.100.3 lookup 6000
32000:  from 192.0.2.2 lookup 5000
32765:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

When 400 became the lowest preference value, adding a new rule without stating the preference didn't pick 31998 but 499 instead (the next lowest then became 500): as warned, better always state preference for newly added rules when juggling with local lookup.  Initial problem is similar with the added fact that it's not possible to add below the next to lowest (0) being also 0, so 0 gets chosen again.

Thanks for this explanation .. just to solidify my understanding with my case the server expects lot of such rules .. i believe based on your explanation what happened  ip rules were filled as it started descending from 1000 (1000: from all lookup [l3mdev-table]) until at some point it hit 0 and kept adding to it as the lowest existing rule. right?

@MohamedNaiem indeed if you had so many rules, that's one possible reason to trigger this "bug". As written, you can "move" them manually. Duplicate them first with a stated higher preference value, and delete the pref 0 one. Once all are handled the same, the bug will disappear.
